# Torque needed to keep a wheel spinning at high RPM

Tags: friction, wheels

I have a treaded wheel which is 16'' diameter and 4'' across (trailer wheel).

If I want it to spin constantly at 2750 RPM, what amount of torque do I need to apply to combat friction and air resistance?

I need to find this out for one of my projects and I am only knowledgeable of ideal world physics. Is there an equation for measuring non-conservative forces on a spinning wheel (like F= b*v^2)?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Thanks for all the insights. I wanted to get an estimate because I have to choose the proper motor to use in this situation. Much cheaper to know which motor/wheel to go for now than to realize the motor/wheel combination is too weak.
In case I have been misunderstood, I purely want the force to keep the wheel spinning. The wheel isn't moving an object body. So, would any drag (v^2) still apply?

Comment: Depends mostly on the shape of the wheel and the bearings it is running on.

Comment: you are probably right aero drag will scale with `v^2`. proabably easier to measure than to figure out an accurate calculation.

Comment: won't it scale with v^3 ?

Comment: A model might get you into the ballpark, but a lot of the friction forces are difficult to predict.  Go measure.

Comment: @Sol: The air drag scales with the square of the speed.  It is the power that therefore scales with the cube of the speed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop cheers and yes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'm not moving a body of object with the wheel. I purely want to spin the wheel, so would v^2 still apply? It seems like the angle of incidence is virtually 0.

Comment: Yes, the torque will be largely proportional to the square of the speed, but what is the proportionality factor?  Again, it is hard to know all the things that would be required to compute that, so go measure it.

Comment: Wheel air drag is the least of vehicle loads. You want max acceleration vs vehicle drag brake power then choose RPM/V motor for no load

Comment: @TonyStewart I'm planning to build a pitching machine as an independent project. So, it is just a motor-wheel system (no additional moving parts). In this case, will air drag still be the biggest resisting factor? Or will it be friction inside the motor?

Comment: It will be conductive losses from reactive current which may be about 10% of rated current and eddy current losses, which generate heat.  Tires are pretty smooth unlike fans so they don't make much noise or drag.  The motor power is only to reduce the acceleration time to reach full speed where torque declines due to back EMF and is greatest at start by 5x to 8x in most AC motors depending on starter mechanism.  It will be much like a big grinder with a small motor unless you want it to start quick. Start by computing rotational energy then power and time to reach that.

Comment: I see. So, if I do not mind lower wheel acceleration, will I still reach about the same equilibrium speed with a 250W motor as I would with a 350W motor if both of them have rated speed of 2750 rpm?
I just don't want to pump more current through my 250W motor than its rated amount and harm it. I appreciate your feedback, I'm learning a lot.